# Select creating a new object is not setting a second level entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am facing an issue when creating a new object like the example below, when setting the parameter `Users` is not including the child entity `Address`.

This issue is just happening when passing to a new object.

```
var services = _serviceDbSet
                  .Include(b => b.Users)
                  .Include(b => b.Users.Select(x => x.Address))
                  .Select(s => new    
                               {
                                    Id = s.Id,
                                    Users = s.Users
                               });
```

Comment: It should work as expected. Do you get it when you do not select *new object*?

Comment: It's known that `Include` does not work (is ignored) with projection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to materialize a user collection like this

```
.Select(s => new    
{
Id = s.Id,
Users = s.Users.ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: the query should to be queryable, the code above is just a simple example of what I need, I need to include one second level entity of one complex existing code. So the include would be enough to solve that but is not, I don't know why is not returning that second level. I tried your solution anyway an it didn't return either.

Comment: When you call ToList(), the result will be queryable (but not from the database anymore). If your have a database queryable at the moment you assign it to Users, add Include at this level. Like `Users = someDBquery.Include("DownLevelEntity")`

Comment: Yes, I need it to be queryable from the database

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could make the projection (Select) in memory.

```
var services = _serviceDbSet
              .Include(b => b.Users)
              .Include(b => b.Users.Select(x => x.Address))
              .ToList()
              .Select(s => new    
                           {
                                Id = s.Id,
                                Users = s.Users
                           });
```

In this case the projection will contain objects with proxies/includes